# How do you split by continuous spaces when some entries have need to be split from a different location

Tags: python, regex

I have the following and I'm trying to split it into Key: Value dictionary where the key is the protocol+version and the value is whether it's supported or not.

```
['SSLv2      not offered (OK)',
 'SSLv3      not offered (OK)',
 'TLS 1      not offered',
 'TLS 1.1    not offered',
 'TLS 1.2    offered (OK)',
 'TLS 1.3    not offered and downgraded to a weaker protocol',
 'NPN/SPDY   h2, http/1.1 (advertised)',
 'ALPN/HTTP2 h2, http/1.1 (offered)']
```

My problem is that I can't figure out a neat way to split this, I can't split by tabs since the data uses spaces, and I can't split by space because some protocols have space there as well. Example:

```
re.split(r'\s+', entries.strip(), 1)
['SSLv2', 'not offered (OK)'], ['SSLv3', 'not offered (OK)'], ['TLS', '1      not offered'], ['TLS', '1.1    not offered'], ['TLS', '1.2    offered (OK)'], ['TLS', '1.3    not offered and downgraded to a weaker protocol'], ['NPN/SPDY', 'h2, http/1.1 (advertised)'], ['ALPN/HTTP2', 'h2, http/1.1 (offered)']]
```

As you can see they all work mostly ok except for some protocols like: `['ALPN/HTTP2', 'h2, http/1.1 (offered)']`

This is what the original data looks like:

```
SSLv2      not offered (OK)
SSLv3      not offered (OK)
TLS 1      not offered
TLS 1.1    not offered
TLS 1.2    offered (OK)
TLS 1.3    not offered and downgraded to a weaker protocol
NPN/SPDY   h2, http/1.1 (advertised)
ALPN/HTTP2 h2, http/1.1 (offered)
```

And I want my final output to look like this:

```
{
    'SSLv2': 'not offered (OK)',
    'SSLv3': 'not offered (OK)',
    'TLS 1': 'not offered',
    'TLS 1.1': 'not offered',
    'TLS 1.2': 'offered (OK)',
    'TLS 1.3': 'not offered and downgraded to a weaker protocol',
    'NPN/SPDY': 'h2, http/1.1 (advertised)',
    'ALPN/HTTP2': 'h2, http/1.1 (offered)'
}
```

Comment: How can you identify the version part?

Comment: It doesnt seem consistent. Some versions have only one space separation from the protocol, and in some other cases the text is also one space away

Comment: It's always the leftmost chunk of it, like `TLS 1` `SSLv3`. I'll paste the program output

Comment: It is not clear what output you want. Do you mean to say `h2` is part of a protocol?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've updated my question with better details

Comment: `dict(re.findall(r'^(\S+(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?)\s+(.*)', entry.strip()))`, see https://ideone.com/MF0VRg

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah that's exactly what I needed. Thank you, could you post as an answer?

Comment: What utility are you using to get the data? It may have a option to emit a machine readable json / xml payload.

Comment: The rule for splitting cannot be inferred from an example. You need to state the rule, in words, at the outset. Here's a possible rule, as an example: "If the string has multiple contiguous spaces, split on the first group of multiple contiguous spaces; if not, split on the first space". Is that your rule?

Comment: If the example rule I gave in my previous comment is correct, you can split each string `s` in Ruby with `s.split(/\s\s+|(?!=\A.*  .*\z)\s/,2)`, the `2` specifying the line is to be split into at most two pieces (i.e., the splitting is to terminate after the first match). The regex reads, "match two or more contiguous whitespaces or do not match two contiguous whitespaces in the string (`(?!...)` being a negative lookahead) and match a whitespace character." Though I'm not familiar with Python, I understand there are many similarities with Ruby, so maybe there is a Python equivalent...

Comment: ...Note that one cannot write `arr = s.split(/\s\s+|(?!=\A.* .*\z)\s/)` (for which there certainly is a Python counterpart), with the key being the first element of the array `arr` and value being the remaining elements joined into a string with a space between each element, as that may remove multiple contiguous whitespaces from some values, though that's not the case in the example and may not be a problem in any event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex with `re.findall`:

```
^(\S+(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?)\s+(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yNVWBw/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S+(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?)` - Group 1:

  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
  - `(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1+ whitespaces, 1+ digits and then 0+ occurrences of `.` and 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the line/string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MF0VRg):

```
import re

entries = ['SSLv2      not offered (OK)', 'SSLv3      not offered (OK)', 'TLS 1      not offered', 'TLS 1.1    not offered', 'TLS 1.2    offered (OK)', 'TLS 1.3    not offered and downgraded to a weaker protocol', 'NPN/SPDY   h2, http/1.1 (advertised)', 'ALPN/HTTP2 h2, http/1.1 (offered)']
for entry in entries:
    print( dict(re.findall(r'^(\S+(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?)\s+(.*)', entry.strip())) )
```

Output:

```
{'SSLv2': 'not offered (OK)'}
{'SSLv3': 'not offered (OK)'}
{'TLS 1': 'not offered'}
{'TLS 1.1': 'not offered'}
{'TLS 1.2': 'offered (OK)'}
{'TLS 1.3': 'not offered and downgraded to a weaker protocol'}
{'NPN/SPDY': 'h2, http/1.1 (advertised)'}
{'ALPN/HTTP2': 'h2, http/1.1 (offered)'}
```

Comment: Or, probably, https://ideone.com/yRtdJd is a better illustration.